# How to build an array by function handle

Tags: arrays, matlab, function-handle

I am trying to produce something like this in MATLAB with function handle

```
f=@(x,y)(x(1)*x(2)+y);

c=[2 3 4;5 9 2];

h=[5 1 2];

f(c,h)
```

The answer should be:

```
15    11    12
```

But when I write this code below, it just builds a number not an array.

```
f=@(x)(x(1)*x(2))

f(c)
```

answer:

```
10
```

Can someone explain me where I went wrong?

Comment: What is it that you find wrong? What is your intended result?

Comment: Being pedantically literal, where you went wrong is in expecting 2*5 to be anything _other_ than 10. `x(1)` and `x(2)` are [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) to single elements of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you expected here. The cause of the problem is quite clear.

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = [3 4];
d = a*b+c;
```

is a `scalar + vector` operation which always returns

```
ans = [a*b+c(1), a*b+c(2)];
```

however `scalar*scalar` which was the second case always returns a scalar. What you do is that you multiply the first matrix element of x (or c) with the second element. That is to say element `c(1,1)*c(2,1)` since matlab works columnwise. If you looks at your values you would probably notice the answer is incorrect as well, if you are trying to do what I think you are. You could try this instead,

```
f=@(x,y)(x(1,:).*x(2,:)+y);
c=[2 3 4;5 9 2];
h=[5 1 2];
f(c,h)
```

which multipies the elements on the first row of x with the same column on the second row and then adds y. An anonymous function takes a number of inputs and perform a defined operation, the same as ordinary functions or ordinary codes. You can see them as functions that does not require a call to another m file. The main differences (except that ordinary functions gives more freedom), are how they are handled by matlab and not in the syntax.